# PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'CHEM_PHYSICAL_PROPERTIES' not allowed in this context

Tags: java, oracle

I'm trying to execute dynamic query SQL 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE' but facing issue as 'PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference CHEM_PHYSICAL_PROPERTIES not allowed in this context' where 'CHEM_PHYSICAL_PROPERTIES' is my dynamic table name. Please suggest the solution on this.

Initially tried to execute same thing using 'SYS_REFCURSOR' but unable to do it for dynamic table name of type %rowtype. i.e.

code 1:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateTargetVal(rowNumber VARCHAR2,p_table_name VARCHAR2, p_object_Id VARCHAR2)  
    IS
    v_my_object_record chem_physical_properties%ROWTYPE;
    cur_records SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
   --This procedure modified afterwards without SYS_REFCURSOR
    Pr_get_result(p_table_name,p_object_Id,cur_records);
     IF (cur_records IS NOT NULL)
    THEN
        LOOP
            FETCH cur_records INTO v_my_object_record;
            EXIT WHEN cur_records%NOTFOUND;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----'||v_my_object_record.min_value);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE cur_records;
    END IF;

   END updateTargetVal;
```

Code 2: Then In order to solve dynamic table name '%rowtype' problem proceed with below solution, but getting above issue. so please suggest the way forward.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Pr_get_result (p_table_name VARCHAR2,p_object_Id VARCHAR2)
    IS
    p_prop_code VARCHAR2(50)    := 'pH';

    BEGIN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
          'DECLARE '                                             ||
            '    TYPE ObjCurTyp  IS REF CURSOR; '                ||
            '    v_obj_cursor    ObjCurTyp; '                    ||
            '    v_stmt_str    VARCHAR2(1000); '                 ||
            '    v_obj_record   ' || p_table_name || '%rowtype; '||
            'BEGIN '                                             || 
         ' v_stmt_str := ''SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM :p_table_name where CREATED_DATE<= (SELECT CREATED_DATE FROM :p_table_name WHERE object_id='||p_object_Id||' AND PROPERTY_CODE='||p_prop_code||') Order By CREATED_DATE DESC) WHERE ROWNUM <= 5'';'  ||
            '    OPEN v_obj_cursor '                             ||
            '        FOR v_stmt_str USING '                      || 
                    p_table_name  || ';'                         ||
            '    LOOP '                                          ||
            '        FETCH v_obj_cursor INTO v_obj_record; '     ||
            '           EXIT WHEN v_obj_cursor %NOTFOUND; '      ||
            '    END LOOP; '                                     ||
            'END;';                   

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind variables cannot be used in this context. 
Just remove `USING` clause and don't use it, but concatenate the table name directly to SQL string instead, just like:

```
v_stmt_str := ''SELECT ...... SELECT * FROM ' || p_table_name  || ' WHERE ..... 
       ......
       ...... T CREATED_DATE FROM ' || p_table_name || ' WHERE obj .....
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now facing 'ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis' problem for the same. calling stored procedure as,  exec Pr_get_result ('chem_physical_properties', '86435A63723D0281E053020011ACEA92');                                                                                                                       ' v_stmt_str := ''SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM '|| p_table_name ||' where CREATED_DATE<= ( SELECT CREATED_DATE FROM '|| p_table_name ||' WHERE object_id='|| p_object_Id ||' AND PROPERTY_CODE='|| p_prop_code || ' ) Order By CREATED_DATE DESC ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 5''; '